# Copy multiple columns from multiple sheets to different columns of another sheet [Google App Script]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple sheets that I need to consolidate into a single main spreadsheet.
I wanted columns C, D and E from `sheet1` copied over to `sheet2` under columns A, C & D respectively.

Is there any way to achieve that using app script?

Answer (score 0):

One way is with query. On Sheet2 enter in the following cells

```
A1: =QUERY( Sheet1!A:G , "Select C" )
C1: =QUERY( Sheet1!A:G , "Select D" )
D1: =QUERY( Sheet1!A:G , "Select E" )
```

Adjust the Sheet1 range to suit your needs.
Another way is enter thia in A1:

```
=QUERY( Sheet1!A:E , "Select C,'', D, E Label ''''" )
```